# Backbone.js: add event of a collection not firing

Tags: events, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a standard Backbone.js collection defined like this:

```
class Observation extends Backbone.Model

class Observations extends Backbone.Collection
  model: Observation
```

I then bind the add event like this in an event handler for the collection's reset event:

```
  collectionReset: (collection) =>
    @collection.bind 'add', @elementAdded
```

The problem is that the event is not being fired.  I have set a break point and walked through the code and it is the following line (627 of backbone.js 0.5.3) that is stopping the add event from firing:

```
_onModelEvent: function (ev, model, collection, options) {
  if ((ev == 'add' || ev == 'remove') && collection != this) return;
```

And it is specifically the following comparison:

```
collection != this
```

The collection argument is different from the 'this' reference.

Has anyone else seen this happening before or can they point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you calling `@collection.bind 'add', @elementAdded` ?

Comment: I've updated the question. I have tried adding the bind in both the initializer of the view and in the reset event handler that I have outlined above.

Comment: Did you set the correct scope for your callback? See: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-this

Comment: I have tried adding the extra argument and still no cigar.  I had the event handler declared with the fat arrow syntax anyway elementAdded: (item) => so I think that would have been covered anyway.

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm not well versed in Coffeescript. What is the value of `this` when doing the failing comparison?

Comment: The `_onModelEvent` function is bound to the collection in the `Backbone.Collection` constructor. Unless you've overridden that constructor (which should create other problems), I can't see how `collection != this` would be satisfied. Nor should it matter how/where you bind the `'add'` callback. Where's the code that you're expecting to trigger the `'add'` event? Are you doing something more complex than `observations.add observation`?

Comment: In `collectionReset` `@collection` doesn't necessarily equal the `collection` you passed in. You might want to log both and make sure you're binding correctly there? It's hard to say without seeing everything.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of suspicious things in your code; your collectionReset method takes a `collection` parameter, but then it looks like you try to bind it you use `@collection`, which is something different. If you really want to call bind on the parameter "collection" being passed, you need to use `collection.bind`, not `@collection.bind` .

I mostly bind events from model classes (including Collections) to Views, and in that case, you normally just refer to the model for binding, i.e. calling `@model.bind 'add', someMethod`. From your code defining `Observations`, it seems you should try something similar.